# How can I display solr date to user format

Tags: java, solr

In solr, I have following records, column name are userdate, firstname and lastname

```
2011-12-25T15:04:36.73Z abc xyz                          
2011-12-26T15:04:36.73Z yyy bbb                      
2011-12-26T15:04:36.73Z test one
```

In UI, Instead of display date and time, I like to display that userdate to following manner(As per user timezone),
            1. While fetching date from solr, it will give only by UTC format.
            2. First Covert UTC format to user timezone, then I like to display userdate to following manner

```
1 day ago abc xyz              
3 hour ago yyy yyy                              
5 second ago test one
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Joda time](http://joda.sourceforge.net/) API to parse date and use [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html) class method to get difference between two date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
    1) Get the interval time in second between the current time and the time got from Solr,
    2) Convert this delta value to different time unit.

and TimeUnit will help a lots

```
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(long duration);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(long duration);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(long duration);
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(long duration);
```

Try the above code in order until you get a value greater then zero and you know the time span and the time unit.

Answer (score 0):

```
var publish = new Date("2016-11-17T09:22:24Z");
alert(publish);
```